# Pages Disappearance in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

recently I have come across a problem in which sometimes ,the contents of some aspx pages in the visual studio just disappear , like this:

[image: showing page]

do you know why this happens and how can I fix it or how can I recover the pages?

Comment: Questions like this should always mention the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: Can I say what my Anti-Virus is or I should I be banned for more one week?